Why is the direction of friction inwards in a rotating disc even though there is no motion in the inward direction?
So, I was studying circular motion and I learnt that when an object is placed on a rotating disc, friction acts inwards to provide the necessary centripetal acceleration and facilitates the circular motion. However, previously I had learnt that friction acts in a direction opposite to the direction of motion. In this case I believe that it should act at 180⁰ to the tangential acceleration. Since, if the object loses contact that is where it will proceed to move. I have been struggling to understand why the friction is acting inwards. Please explain in simple words. I read similar posts but couldn't really understand.

Look up the difference between static friction and dynamical friction.

"Static friction is a force that acts in the direction opposite to the tendency of relative motion. For example, when you gently push a bed with your finger, the bed doesn't move because of static friction acting in the opposite direction of the applied force." Got this from Google. But how to correlate this with the friction acting on the object.There is no force acting radially outward. ??@MariusLadegårdMeyer

Since you confused about relative motion between the thing ($m$ at $R$) on the disc (spinning at $\omega$), let's solve it in a rotating frame so that every thing is at rest $(v=0)$, it's a statics problem:
The Coriolis force zero:
$$ \vec F_C = 2m(\vec \omega \times \vec v) = 0 $$
The centrifugal force is not:
$$ \vec F_c = m(\vec \omega \times (\vec \omega \times \vec R)) =
m \omega^2 R\hat r$$
which is outward. Since the thing is not moving, there must be a force opposing the outward centrifugal force since:
$$ \vec F_{\mu} + \vec F_c + \vec F_C = 0 $$
so
$$ \vec F_{\mu} = -\vec F_c = -m\omega^2 R \hat r $$
which points inward.

Thanks this really helps.


However, previously I had learnt that friction acts in a direction
opposite to the direction of motion

That applies to kinetic friction which acts opposite to relative motion that is underway between surfaces. The friction acting on the object on the rotating disc is static friction which prevents relative motion (sliding) between the object and the rotating disc.

In this case I believe that it should act at 180⁰ to the tangential
acceleration.

If the disc is rotating at constant angular velocity, there is no tangential acceleration. If there was tangential acceleration, then static friction would be needed 180$^0$ to the tangential acceleration to prevent the object from sliding on the disc.

I have been struggling to understand why the friction is acting
inwards. Please explain in simple words.

Think about what would happen to the object if static friction between the object and the disc suddenly disappeared. When you do, it is important to consider the frame of reference where the observation is made.
An observer in an inertial (non accelerating) frame would see the object fly off the disc in a direction tangent to the circular motion. That observer would attribute the motion to Newton's first law which says an object will remain at rest or move at constant speed in a straight line unless acted upon by an external force. The static friction force is the external force that prevents the object from moving in a straight line due to its inertia. It keeps pulling the object towards the center of rotation.
An observer at the center of the rotating disc (a non inertial frame) would see the object move radially outward, and would attribute the motion to a net force outwards, in this case the centrifugal force, which is a fictitious force used to apply Newton's laws in a non inertial reference frame.
Hope this helps.

Thanks a lot. I do understand it now.

Friction acts opposite of the direction of relative motion if friction wasn't there.
In the absence of friction an object placed on a rotating disk (carefully to match the velocity of the object on the contact point) will follow a straight line path from that point on. The point of contact on the disk will follow an arc.
Relative to the contact point on the disk the object appears to move radially outwards initially, and thus friction should act radially inwards if the object is to maintain contact as the disk rotates.
More complicated things happen if the object slips because the direction of motion changes, and thus the direction of friction changes also.

I realize that this way of approaching friction can lead to confusion, so I like to think of friction a bit backwards.
Imagine the object was glued to the disk and rotating around. The in-plane contact forces that keep the object glued will be in the radially inwards direction. This scenario is like infinite friction is available.
For finite friction keep the direction of the friction force the same, but limit its magnitude to the available traction. Looking at the equations of motion, this will result in some relative motion in the direction opposite of the friction force as it will not be sufficiently large to hold the object glued anymore.
At the limit, you have the frictionless situation with the magnitude of the friction force being zero, and the result of the analysis proceeding the same way.

First, friction acts opposite the direction of relative motion between the surfaces, not opposite motion relative to any frame of reference. Furthermore, static friction acts when there is no relative motion between the surfaces; surfaces do not need to be sliding past each other in order for friction to be present.
Second, if the object is undergoing uniform circular motion, then the net force acting on it must be directed towards the center of the circle; it is completely radially inward without any tangential component. If friction is the only force acting with a component in the plane of the circle, then the friction force must be equal to the net force, and hence it must also point toward the center of the circle.

sorry! Didn't quite understand. Let me tell you what's going on in my head rn. I am thinking there is no force acting radially outwards. So how is the friction acting inwards.?? I understand that to move around it needs centripetal acceleration. We had another example taken in class. It was a stone tied by a rope on a rod and it was made to revolve. I understood there that tension in the rope acted as centripetal acceleration. But here, it just makes me confused.
